# MKAnnotation rotating when pinching the map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have an app where I am tracking someone who walks. Once I get the users heading, I rotate the MKAnnotationView based on the heading. Everything works when tracking and rotating the MKAnnotationView except for when move or pinch the map. When I pinch or move the map the MKAnnotationView appears to redraw back to the starting state point at 0 or North. On the next update front the heading, x and y then the MKAnnotation rotates back to the correct heading.

I think the issue has to do with the way I am rotating the MKAnnotation based on heading. I think the map redraws the MKAnnotation and sets back the CGAffineTransformMakeRotation I have set.

```
if(bearing < 0 || bearing > 0) 
{

   MKAnnotationView* anView = [self.mapView viewForAnnotation: self.movingAssignedAmbObject ];
   [anView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DegreesToRadians([bearing floatValue]))];

}
```

Is there a way to stop the draw from rotating my annotation back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a transform on the MKAnnotationView, I think you are going to need a custom MKAnnotationView subclass where you have a rotation transform on the *image* that the annotation view draws.

Comment: Add a UIImageView to my custom MKAnnotationView and it works like a charm! THX.